# Sources for sampling in case-control studies

Tags: sampling, statistical-power, case-control-study

In my previous job as a statistics teacher, I was involved in studies mostly as an advisor on a general level. Not that much hands-on experience from doing the actual sampling or data cleaning, activities which are both important and time-consuming in practice. In my present job, I am the one who is supposed to know about the practical details of sampling, sample size calculations and such, and I have realized that there are missing bits of knowledge in my toolbox.

The question right now concerns sampling in a case-control study. Are there any good sources (books, web sites,...) covering the more practical aspects with advice for modern software, selection of controls, power calculations and such? I have found several routines in both SPSS and R for selection, but it would be interesting to put these into a more general framework.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Robert. Can you expand your question and provide more details as to what you want to figure out?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Scott's article is clearly interesting. Here's a slightly more specific question: what is the best matching procedure in a simple study involving patients and controls drawn from a register of all indivuals in the region, a setup with the controls stratified by age and sex or using procedures for "fuzzy" matching (fuzzy as used in for example SPSS)? As I have understood the latter, the selection finds individuals in the control set which are "close" to the cases.    Furthermore, are there any standard text books covering practicalities of case-control studies?

Comment: I have no clue what SPSS  does, and frankly would prefer understanding what a package does before using it. Stratifying by age and sex would sound good enough for me, unless there are some other covariates known to affect the outcome that can be stratified upon. Matching that is too picky may not generalize well for the controls that it could never pick, although one can argue that only the individuals at risk in the general population that are "close enough" to cases are of the primary interest, anyway. (Economists like to put forth that sort of argument in their local treatment effects).

Answer (score 1):

Alastair Scott's invited Waksberg lecture on population-based case-control studies may be worth looking at: http://www.statcan.gc.ca/ads-annonces/12-001-x/9546-eng.pdf. He's published a lot on this topic, and I would say he is the best authority.